# Android client server programming.

Tags: android, jsp, servlets

I want to learn Android client server communication programming. I don't like PHP much I had learnt at college that Servlet and JSP help us to achieve client server communication and I want to learn something on this pattern. Can anyone please suggest me some nice neat tutorials for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side, there are many tutorials, such as this one (http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/) that can show you how to make HTTP requests from your android application using the [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) class.

On the server-side, it's hard to point to a single resource as there are many. But you can start at servlet world: http://www.servletworld.com/

Comment: Thanks mate, I will start from here.

Answer (score 2):

The Android developer portal has a collection of really good [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).   I would recommend starting there if you are interested in building native apps.   If you have familiarity with the standard front-end stack (HTML, CSS, JavaScript), check out [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).